# Plugins try to install in old location

Tags: installation

I just moved my WordPress website to a new domain & server. Everything seems to work fine except for installing new plugins. When I'm trying to install a new plugin, it's still trying to access the upload directory of the old server.

The error I get is:

```
Warning: touch() [function.touch]: Unable to create file /home/oldserver/domains/olddomain.com/public_html/website/wp-content/uploads/search-and-replace.tmp because Permission denied in /home/newserver/domains/newdomain.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 179

Warning: unlink(/home/oldserver/domains/olddomain.com/public_html/website/wp-content/uploads/search-and-replace.tmp) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in /home/newserver/domains/newdomain.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 493
```

I already changed the `WordPress URL`, `Site URL` and `Upload Directory` in the database `wp_options` table. What did I miss?

Comment: can we see your wp-config.php?

Comment: Thanks, found the solution while clearing sensitive data. Will post my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `wp-config.php` under the different salts there was a line, which I missed because it was directly under the different salts.

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR',      '/home/oldserver/domains/olddomain.be/public_html/website/wp-content/uploads');
```

Obviously that needed to be changed to the new server path as well.